# List of plotting options

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I often use the same plotting arguments for Plot3D so I tried to make a list so I do not have to write them over and over.

I tried:

optlist = {Boxed->False, Axes->True, AxesOrigin->{0,0,0}};

Plot3D[eq, {x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}, optlist];

I am not a programmer and use Mathematica only for math-study.

Comment: Your question is answered in detail in these posts: Related: [(3247)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3247/121), [(20718)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20718/121), [(22697)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22697/121).  Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20592283/618728) recent answer of mine which describes the cause of the failure and gives several solutions.